# nvidia-drm module will not be installed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, nvidia, google-dl-platform

I was using `/opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh` script to install nvidia driver. But I got following error saying that the nvidia-drm module was not installed. I have two questions:

1. Is this module required to run cuda?
2. How to fix it?

```
WARNING: The nvidia-drm module will not be installed. As a result, DRM-KMS will not function with this installation of the NVIDIA driver.


WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib64' and X module path '/usr/lib64/xorg/modules'; these paths were not
         queryable from the system.  If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org
         SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.
```

This is a Google Deep Learning VM.
Version: common-cu113.m91
Based on: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (GNU/Linux 4.19.0-20-cloud-amd64 x86_64\n)

Comment: Have you tried to update your kernel? and the repository of your OS? Please add details to your issue, what OS do you use.

Comment: @BryanL Yes, I update & upgrade the kernel of the VM. 
Speaking of OS, I was wondering if GCP would automatically update the kernel periodically. And I don't know if I was remembering it wrong, I think my os has changed from Centos to Debian somehow by someone else.

Comment: GCP cannot update the kernel in your VM once it is installed. GCP already listed available OS and its versions during VM set up. Also, what GPU type are you using? Make sure that the GPU driver you are trying to install is supported by the one you installed in your VM.